# Footer in each page is not working (Prawn PDF) in rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf, pdf-generation, prawn, prawnto

I have prawn gem installed in my rails 3 application.

I wonder why my footer isn't working in each page.

It is only working at the end of the last page.

Here is my code:

( I am very new to Prawn )

So please bear with me.

Any workarounds will be very much appreciated

```
require 'prawn'
require 'rubygems'
require 'date'

pdf = Prawn::Document.new(:page_layout => :landscape,:skip_page_creation => true,:margin => [5,5,5,5]) do
    start_new_page
    pdf.font "Helvetica"    
end


pdf.text "Project Procurement Management Plan (PPMP)", :size=> 12, :spacing => 4, :align=> :center

pdf.move_down 400


pdf.text "Text"
pdf.text "Text"
pdf.text "Text"
pdf.text "Text"
pdf.text "Text"
pdf.text "Text"
pdf.text "Text"
pdf.text "Text"
pdf.text "Text"
pdf.text "Text"
pdf.text "Text"
pdf.text "Text"
pdf.text "Text"
pdf.text "Text"
pdf.text "Text"
pdf.text "Text"
pdf.text "Text"
pdf.text "Text"
pdf.text "Text"
pdf.text "Text"


# This is the footer code

pdf.bounding_box([pdf.bounds.right - 59, pdf.bounds.bottom - -20], :width => 60, :height => 20) do

  pagecount = pdf.page_count
  pdf.text "Page #{pagecount}"
end
```

**Solved!**

See what I found out below.

Answer (score 3):

Hi i already found out the answer.

For those who are having a trouble like this:

```
pdf.repeat :all do

  pdf.bounding_box [pdf.bounds.left, pdf.bounds.bottom + 25], :width  => pdf.bounds.width do
  pdf.stroke_horizontal_rule
  pdf.move_down(5)
  pdf.text "#{current_user.first_name}", :size => 10
end
end
```

Comment: Haha good to hear, I late to post..haha But glad you found it.

Answer (score 3):

I tried to generate **left/center/right - content** on each page, outside the bottom margin.
`number_pages` only generates one block.
Several apporoaches:

a. use `repeat` and `text_box`. The important thing here is, that `text_box` needs an eplicit height to be displayed outside the bounds:

```
repeat :all do
  text_box "title: some text", at: [bounds.left, -20], height: 20
  text_box "printet at #{Time.now}", height: 20, width: 200, align: :right, at: [bounds.right-200,-20]
end
```

b. you can call `number_pages` several times at the end of the PDF generation. You don't have to provied pages number templates. `number_pages` can generate text outside the bounds (it sets the heigth internally):

```
number_pages "title: some text", at: [bounds.left, -20]
number_pages "page <page> of <total>", at: [300,-20]
number_pages "printed at #{Time.now}", at: [bounds.right-200,-20], width: 200, align: :right
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to display horizontal line separator then this is minimal solution, as the `pdf.number_pages` works even without `pdf.repeat(:all)`:

```
options = {
        :at => [pdf.bounds.right - 150, 0],
        :width => 150,
        :align => :right,
        :start_count_at => 1
}
pdf.number_pages "Page <page> of <total>", options
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
pdf.page_count.times do |i|
  pdf.go_to_page(i+1)
  pdf.bounding_box([0, pdf.bounds.bottom + 25], :width => pdf.bounds.width) {
    pdf.line_width(3)
    pdf.stroke_horizontal_rule
    pdf.move_down(5)
    pdf.draw_text "Page #{i+1}" ,:at => [240, pdf.bounds.height - 20]
    pdf.draw_text "#{Time.now.strftime("%B %d, %Y")}" ,:at => [455, pdf.bounds.height - 20]
  }
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
pdf.repeat(:all) do
  pdf.stroke do
    pdf.horizontal_line 0, 540, :at => 10
  end

  pdf.number_pages "(<page>/<total>)", :size => 9, :at => [500, 0]
end
```

So what I understand, that I need to use this `number_pages` to create it, basically what I do wasn't clean and right, because for create header and footer I use all with `number_pages` but I work since with it we can freely assign it's position, and it's simple.